# need help resizing floating table

Tags: tables, two-column

[image]

Hello all!

Any suggestions for this issue here?

Thanks!

Here is the code I am currently working with:

```
\section{Empirical Results}

\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
\begingroup
\begin{table}[h]
\caption {\label{tab:table1} Estimates of Pay-Performance Sensitivity: Coefficients of Ordinary Least Squares Regressions of CEO Salary on Shareholder Wealth (Standard Error in Parentheses} 
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
 Independent Variable 
 & CEO Salary & CEO Total Compensation                                      & \\    
 \hline
 Intercept   &  0.0555555   & 0.055556 \\       
 Change in Shareholder Wealth (\% Change) & 0.0408163 (.05) & .025 (.05) \\      
R-square & .005 & .005 \\ 
F-statistic for $\beta$ & 0.0246913\footnotemark[1] & 0.024691\footnotemark[1] & \\
Sample Size  &  0.0199999   & 0.020000 \\                                                   
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabbing}
$\footnotemark[1]$Significant at the 1\% Level.
\end{tabbing}
\end{table}
\endgroup
```

---

When I try to implement @bernard's code, I run into some issues with the code:

```
\newcommand{\rvec}{\mathrm {\mathbf {r}}} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color, soul}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makecell, threeparttable, booktabs}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\usepackage{lipsum}
```

This^ results in an error, as well as the following code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}  
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

---

Edit for @samcarter, I will go with the column width table. Can I improve it from here or is this as good as it's going to get? It looks awkward in a few places:

[image]

Here's the code that was provided to me to create it:

```
\section{Empirical Results}
%TABLE:
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{\label{tab:table1} Estimates of Pay-Performance Sensitivity: Coefficients of Ordinary Least Squares Regressions of CEO Salary on Shareholder Wealth (Standard Error in Parentheses} 
    \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}XXX@{}}
        \toprule
        Independent Variable & CEO Salary & CEO Total Compensation\\    
        \midrule
        Intercept   &  0.0555555   & 0.055556 \\       
        Change in Shareholder Wealth (\% Change) & 0.0408163 (.05) & .025 (.05) \\      
        R-square & .005 & .005 \\ 
        F-statistic for $\beta$ & 0.0246913\footnotemark[1] & 0.024691\footnotemark[1] \\
        Sample Size  & 0.0199999 & 0.020000\\
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabularx}
    \begin{tabbing}
        $\footnotemark[1]$Significant at the 1\% Level.
    \end{tabbing}
\end{table}
```

Thanks again!

---

**Edit 4/23**:

Here is where I am now. (Getting an error at `\end{tabularx}`):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}                                                         

\usepackage{graphicx}

%for table
\newcommand{\rvec}{\mathrm {\mathbf {r}}} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color, soul}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}

%TABLE:
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{\label{tab:table1} Estimates of Pay-Performance Sensitivity: Coefficients of Ordinary Least Squares Regressions of CEO Salary on Shareholder Wealth (Standard Error in Parentheses} 
    \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}LLL@{}}
        \toprule
        Independent Variable & CEO Salary & CEO Total Compensation\\    
        \midrule
        Intercept   &  0.0555555   & 0.055556 \\       
        Change in Shareholder Wealth (\% Change) & 0.0408163 (.05) & .025 (.05) \\      
        R-square & .005 & .005 \\ 
        F-statistic for $\beta$ & 0.0246913\footnotemark[1] & 0.024691\footnotemark[1] \\
        Sample Size  & 0.0199999 & 0.020000\\
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabularx}
    \begin{tabbing}
        $\footnotemark[1]$Significant at the 1\% Level.
    \end{tabbing}
\end{table}
```

Comment: have a look at the `tabularx` package. If you'd post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) helping you would be easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never use `\resizebox` with a table: it leads to inconsistent font sizes, and can make your tables unreadable. I suggest loading `makecell`, which allows for line breaks in standard cells, and `threeparttable` to manage table notes, rather than the `tabbing` environment. Here is posssible code, with some improvements  the rules from `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makecell, threeparttable, booktabs}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

 \section{Empirical Results}

\lipsum[1]
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption {\label{tab:table1} Estimates of Pay-Performance Sensitivity: Coefficients of Ordinary Least Squares Regressions of CEO Salary on Shareholder Wealth (Standard Error in Parentheses}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
\thead[l]{ Independent\\ Variable}
 & CEO Salary & \thead[l]{CEO Total\\ Compensation} \\
 \midrule
 Intercept & 0.0555555 & 0.055556 \\
 \thead[l]{Change in \\Shareholder Wealth\\ (\% Change)} &\makecell[l]{0.0408163\\ (.05)} & \makecell[l]{0.025\\ (.05)} \\
R-square & 0.005 & 0.005 \\
F-statistic for $\beta$ & 0.0246913\tnote{1} & 0.024691\tnote{1} \\
Sample Size & 0.0199999 & 0.020000 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\smallskip\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\item[1]Significant at the 1\,\% Level.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! When I swap out this document class for the one I currently have, there is an error, and when I add the packages you posted, I also get an error. How should I implement these changes?

Comment: Could you post (or link to) a small document showing the problem?

Comment: I will show my problem in the original post

Comment: @user159324: The reason is quite simple; you loaded the `ieeeconf` class first, then the `article` class. You can declare two classes for the same document. Drop the latter. Some other remarks: for the  definition of `\vec`, `\lmathbf` is enough (it is an upright font). Also, package `subfigure` is obsolete (not maintained for more than 12 years), use the `subfigure` environment from `subfloat`. Also, needless to load `color` if you load `xcolor` (with option `[table]` if you use colour in tables, as it loads `colortbl` and extends it). Last, if your input encoding is `utf8`, load `soulutf8`.

Answer (score 2):

Your table is wider than your column. To squeeze it into the column width, you could use a `tabularx` environment, which will automatically determine the available width for the columns and add line breaks as needed.

Furthermore I suggest to use the `booktabs` package for nicer tables.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\section{Empirical Results}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{\label{tab:table1} Estimates of Pay-Performance Sensitivity: Coefficients of Ordinary Least Squares Regressions of CEO Salary on Shareholder Wealth (Standard Error in Parentheses} 
    \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}LLL@{}}
        \toprule
        Independent Variable & CEO Salary & CEO Total Compensation\\    
        \midrule
        Intercept   &  0.0555555   & 0.055556 \\       
        Change in Shareholder Wealth (\% Change) & 0.0408163 (.05) & .025 (.05) \\      
        R-square & .005 & .005 \\ 
        F-statistic for $\beta$ & 0.0246913\footnotemark[1] & 0.024691\footnotemark[1] \\
        Sample Size  & 0.0199999 & 0.020000\\
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabularx}
    \begin{tabbing}
        $\footnotemark[1]$Significant at the 1\% Level.
    \end{tabbing}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

### [image]

---

Another possibility: With `table*`, the table can span both columns

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\section{Empirical Results}

\begin{table*}[htbp]
    \caption{\label{tab:table1} Estimates of Pay-Performance Sensitivity: Coefficients of Ordinary Least Squares Regressions of CEO Salary on Shareholder Wealth (Standard Error in Parentheses} 
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        \toprule
        Independent Variable & CEO Salary & CEO Total Compensation\\    
        \midrule
        Intercept   &  0.0555555   & 0.055556 \\       
        Change in Shareholder Wealth (\% Change) & 0.0408163 (.05) & .025 (.05) \\      
        R-square & .005 & .005 \\ 
        F-statistic for $\beta$ & 0.0246913\footnotemark[1] & 0.024691\footnotemark[1] \\
        Sample Size  & 0.0199999 & 0.020000\\
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tabbing}
        $\footnotemark[1]$Significant at the 1\% Level.
    \end{tabbing}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the response. I'm new to overleaf and latex. How do I implement those first lines of code? Do I go back to the beginning of the document and just copy and paste it in? Thanks again!

Comment: @user159324 The `\usepackage` stuff has to be somewhere before `\begin{document}`, the table obviously where you want it to be.

Comment: thank you for these example tables. Very helpful. I like the look of the latter one, but can this not go into the body of the paper? It won't copy and paste into the empirical results section. I also like the look of the one that is column width, but I get an error in this case: "LaTeX Error: Environment tabularx undefined." Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: @user159324 For using `tabularx` you need to load the package of the same name. As for your problems with the two column solution: please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: please see the original post for a follow-up question. thanks!

Comment: @user159324 Maybe left aligned would be better than justified columns

Comment: Do you mean simply left-justifying things manually? Or does this take an adjustment in the code?

Comment: @user159324 See my edit

Comment: after trying to implement your edit, I get an error at the line "\end{tabularx}"

Comment: @user159324 Then please make a MWE that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I edited the original document. Let me know if you need any more information about the table.

Comment: @user159324 You did not copy all the packages and definitions from my preamble

Answer (score 2):

(This answer addresses only the most recent version of the OP's query, which is marked "Edit 4/23".)

Note to OP: If you have a substantially new question, you should post a new query. Otherwise, the answers that were posted previously (and which were hopefully helpful) become meaningless to future readers of your posting.

The reason your latest code doesn't compile -- other than the fact tbat it's missing `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` statements -- is that you didn't define the `L` column type.

I can't help but remark that your table is confusing and hence not easy to undertand. For instance, the legend refers to *one* dependent variable (CEO salary), but the table clearly reports the results of *two* regressions, with two separate dependent variables. Worse, assuming the F-statistic numbers you posted are real, it looks like you've misinterpreted the meaning of statistical significance. If the F-statistic is really 0.0247, then there's not a 1% but actually a 99% chance that any (linear) association between the dependent variables and the regressor is due solely to chance. Put differently, it looks like there's an *exceedingly low* likelihood that you've uncovered a meaningful linear relationship between change in shareholder wealth and CEO compensation: Is this what you meant to report? By the way, one usually doesn't need to highlight insignificant statistical results with asterisks.

Incidentally, the F-statistic tests the significance of the entire regression, and not just the significance of an individual regressor and its coefficient `\beta`. By the way, how does one get fractional sample sizes of roughly 0.2? Sample sizes are generally expressed as integers...

Finally, the `subfigure` package has been deprecated for a decade or more. Don't use it! Use either the `subfig` or the `subcaption` package.

Here's my attempt to clean up some of the challenges pointed out above.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}                                                         

\usepackage{graphicx}

%for table
\newcommand{\rvec}{\mathrm {\mathbf {r}}} 
%% \usepackage{graphicx} % no need to load a package twice
%%%%%%\usepackage{subfigure} % don't load this deprecated package!
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
%TABLE:
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{Estimates of pay-performance sensitivity} 
    \label{tab:table1} 
    \raggedright
    OLS regressions of CEO salary and CEO total compensation on change in shareholder wealth. Standard errors in parentheses. 

    \medskip
    \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}LLL @{}}
    \toprule
    Independent variable & CEO salary & CEO total compensation\\    
    \midrule
    Intercept   &  0.0555555   & 0.055556 \\       
    Change in Shareholder Wealth (\%~Change) & 0.0408163 (.05) & .025 (.05) \\  
    \addlinespace    
    R-squared & .005 & .005 \\ 
    F-statistic & 0.0246913$^{*}$ & 0.024691$^{*}$ \\
    Sample Size  & 0.0199999 & 0.020000\\
    \bottomrule 
    \end{tabularx}

    \smallskip
    $^{*}$ Significant at the 1\% level.
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: these numbers were just filler. You are correct . . . that would have been nonsense. Thanks for the heads up though!

Answer (score 1):

as supplement to excellent [@mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico)  answer (with a careful review of statistics), limited only to table design:

[image]

changes are in:

- used `\small` font size in table
- last two columns are of type `l`
- added are vertical space (2pt) above and below cells contents (with `\makegapedcells` from the package `makecell`)
- for the headers of columns is used macro `\thead` from `makecell`

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
%TABLE:
    \begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Estimates of pay-performance sensitivity}
\label{tab:table1}
    \raggedright
OLS regressions of CEO salary and CEO total compensation on change in shareholder wealth. Standard errors in parentheses.

    \medskip
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \small
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}Lll @{}}
    \toprule
\thead[l]{Independent\\ variable} 
            &  \thead[l]{CEO\\salary} 
                                & \thead[l]{CEO total\\ compensation}\\
    \midrule
Intercept   &  0.0555555        & 0.055556          \\
Change in Shareholder Wealth (\%~Change)
            & 0.0408163 (.05)   & 0.025 (.05)       \\
    \addlinespace
R-squared   & 0.005             & 0.005             \\
F-statistic & 0.0246913$^{*}$   & 0.024691$^{*}$    \\
Sample Size & 0.0199999         & 0.020000          \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\smallskip
$^{*}$ Significant at the 1\% level.
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```